# How long should a Primary Key delete take?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-delete

Picture a simple table structure:

```
Table1        Table2
----------    ----------
ID<-------|   ID
Name      |-->Table1ID
              Name
```

`Table1` has a few million rows (say 3.5 million for example). I issue a delete by Primary Key:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 100;
```

There is no row in `Table2` that references `Table1` with `ID = 100`, so the delete works without violating any Foreign Key constraints.

How long would you expect the delete to take? On the order of a few milliseconds? A few hundred milliseconds? A second or more? A few seconds? Etc., assuming the machine is not bogged down and readily handles the request.

Now, I have this situation where a delete like this is taking around 700ms. To me, this seems too slow. I'm curious if I'm off-base or if others agree this is too slow, and recommendations to help make it faster!

Here is the actual execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

(XML Execution plan here: http://pastebin.com/q9hSMLi3)

The Clustered Index Delete (81%) hits the Clustered PK, a Non-Clustered Unique Index, and a Non-Clustered Non-Unique Index.

Comment: When you say *this table has a few million rows* are you talking about `Table1` or `Table2`?  If Table2 has a few millions rows and there's no index on `Table1ID`, this could be pretty slow..

Comment: Sorry, `Table1` has 3.5mil rows.

Comment: Yea, deleting a single row by its primary key should be super fast..  Doing the lookup on Table2 is probably where the slow-down is.  Can you post the execution plan please?

Comment: Could you please post the XML plan? I'm suspicious of the FK validation *Scan*. It should be a seek into an index. I'd also like to check the delete operator and look at the indexes affected.

Comment: @usr - I don't think you can seek into a non-unique index, so it's doing a scan.  Looks like it's spending most of its time on the clustered index, which would be `Table1`, correct?  I'm wondering why that part is taking so long..

Comment: @usr - added XML execution plan link to post. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the clustered index scan to validate the foreign key.

When the delete succeeds and there are no matching records that would cause a violation then all of `table2` needs to be scanned. This table has 1,117,190 rows so this is an expensive operation that could definitely benefit from an index.

The 10% figure shown in the execution plan is just an estimate based on certain modelling assumptions.

The entire plan is costed at `0.0369164` with the scan on table 2 costed at `0.0036199` and everything else accounting for the remaining `0.0332965`. However notice that for the clustered index scan operator the Estimated CPU Cost is `1.22907` and Estimated IO Cost is `10.7142` (totaling `11.94327` not `0.0369164`).

The reason for this discrepancy is that the scan is under an anti semi join operator and the scan can stop as soon as a matching row is found. The estimated subtree cost is scaled down under the modelling assumption that this will happen after only a very small proportion of the table has been scanned.

In the case that there are no FK violations and the delete succeeds then the entire table needs to be scanned so it would be more informative to use the unscaled down figure.

If the percentages are reworked out using the `11.94327` cost for that operator that represents the full scan that happened in practice then this scan operator shows up as being 99.7% of the plan cost (`11.94327 / (11.94327 +  0.0332965)`).

Comment: Thanks, adding an index atop the FK for "Table2" resulted in a 10x faster delete!

Answer (score 1):

If all pages being touched are in cache you can expect about 1ms or less for the CPU cost and the log write. The client library overhead might actually be more in terms of CPU than the server load.

For each page not in cache you can expect a disk seek of 5-10ms on a magnetic disk. Roughly, you can expect one such access per index being touched in `Table1` plus one access in `Table2` to validate the FK.

The execution plan tells you for sure which physical ops are to be performed.

700ms seems like a lot (70 indexes?!). Please post the actual execution plan. The server is unloaded and there is no blocking due to locks?

Comment: Remember that a foreign key isn't indexed by default, so if it has to scan table2 for validation, I highly doubt we are talking about a single page access. Also the PK in table1 might not be clustered. There could also be triggers, CDC, Change Tracking - all kinds of things that can impact the base operation.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the execution plan to the original post.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks. The PK is indeed clustered. As you can see in the execution plan, the FK lookup/validation is 10% of the cost.

Comment: The execution plan shows maintenance for 2 non clustered indexes. @JoshM - It is scanning the whole of a 1,117,190 row table (as you say there are no matches) so that `10%` cost estimate seems woefully wrong. If you index the FK column in table2 things should improve. Maybe it uses [the containment assumption](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/inclusion-of-order-by-on-query-that-returns-no-rows-drastically-affects-performa/10220#10220) here and assumes that the join will likely to return a match. If so doesn't seem that appropriate an assumption in this case.

Comment: @MartinSmith - looks like you're right. I added an index atop the FK and the delete went from 700ms to 73ms. Excellent! Convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - BTW is this something that Plan Explorer could show? If an estimated 1 row is emitted from a scan under a semi join but an actual row count of 0 then you know that a fulll scan must have occurred and any scaling down of costs is invalid.

Comment: Or I suppose more generally the number of rows that are input to the left semi join from the parent minus the number of rows input from the child is the number of full scans that occurred.

Comment: @MartinSmith can you send me a sloppy rendition of what you think the plan should show differently? I'd be happy to take a look but need a concrete example to start from. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I was just thinking that when you select the option to show actual costs it could take into account this issue similar to the calculation in my answer (based on the OP's uploaded execution plan)

Comment: @MartinSmith ok thanks, I will play with this locally and see if I can come up with something.