# Performance slow of Delete query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, database-administration

I have an application which is using Entity framework for DB operations. In an one table when performing the delete operation it takes more than 3 minutes. But other similar tables doesn't take much time. I have debugged the code and find out there is no issue with the code.But executing the query in the sql server took much time.

Any troubleshooting steps/root cause for this issue ?

My table is as below,

```
Id (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
FirstValue(real,not null)
SecondValue(real,not null)
ThirdValue(real,not null)
LastValue(int,not null)
Config_Id(FK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
```

Query Execution Plan
[image]

Comment: How do you delete your data? Otherwise it's hard to answer it.

Comment: How many foreign keys are referencing your table?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas                                                                     
Deleting the data using Entity Framework. Also I check with a query . DELETE FROM [dbo].[Values]
      WHERE [Id] = 'a3e57902-f358-4283-978c-37f9cd00793r'
GO

Comment: @S.Karras Only one foreign key is referred

Comment: @LahiruD that seems to be the best query possible for deletion. Could you attach execution plan by any chance?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I was doing this execution from my application via the repository and service layer .  From the repository it is calling to the Entity Framework Delete method and Save the changes (repo.Delete(ValueClass),repo.UoW.SaveChanges()). After that to return the status of the query execution took the time.

Comment: Can you run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and get us an execution plan? There are guides online telling how to do that.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a foreign key that is set to cascade delete?

Comment: This seems to be somewhat similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845232/how-long-should-a-primary-key-delete-take Try adding a index on a foreign-key column on your Values  table.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Already added a indexing on the foreign key .

Comment: And there's no improvement? Ideally, once delete happens it then should seek your index instead scanning the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't adding up here, we're not seeing the full picture...

There are a multitude of things which can slow down deletes (usually):

- deleting a lot of records (which we know isn't the case here)
- many indexes (which I suspect IS the case here)
- deadlocks and blocking (is this a development or production database?)
- triggers
- cascade delete
- transaction log needing to grow
- many foreign keys to check (I suspect this might also be happening)

Can you please give us a screenshot of the "View Dependencies" feature in SSMS? To get this, right click on the table in the object explorer and select `View Dependencies`.

Also, can you open up a query on the `master` database, run the following queries and post the results:

```
SELECT name, value, value_in_use, minimum, maximum, [description], is_dynamic, is_advanced
FROM sys.configurations WITH (NOLOCK)
where name in (
    'backup compression default',
    'clr enabled',
    'cost threshold for parallelism',
    'lightweight pooling',
    'max degree of parallelism',
    'max server memory',
    'optimize for ad hoc workloads',
    'priority boost',
    'remote admin connections'
)
ORDER BY name OPTION (RECOMPILE);

SELECT DB_NAME([database_id]) AS [Database Name], 
       [file_id], [name], physical_name, [type_desc], state_desc,
       is_percent_growth, growth,
       CONVERT(bigint, growth/128.0) AS [Growth in MB], 
       CONVERT(bigint, size/128.0) AS [Total Size in MB]
FROM sys.master_files WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY DB_NAME([database_id]), [file_id] OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```